# Add Service Reference give me error while url works in browser

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, soap, asp.net-core-mvc

I am try to add service reference in visual studio 2019 with a client url. The URL works on browser successfully but when i try to add it in vs, it gives me error

> The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
> The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
> There was an error downloading 'https://services.com/xml/ecService/misc.xsd'.
> The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved.
> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
> If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I try various post on stackoverflow regarding same, but not able to solve this error. I am new to this so no idea how to solve it. Please guide me for same.

**Note :** Someone told me to use certificate to solve this, but don't know how  to do it.

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27435343

Comment: thanx but it ask for smart card certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your url in credential manager. It works with a certificate.